# Convert youtube video to playable cd on dvd player?

Tags: video-player

I found great videos on youtube and I would like to share them with the family, but my family does not want to watch them crowded together by my computer, but rather would like to watch them in the living room with the dvd player. I have VLC and a cd, but no clue on how to proceed. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you need to download those videos from Youtube by using firefox add-on **downloadhelper**
2. Then insert your cd and open **Brasero disk burner**.
3. Now select Data Project and add those videos in it and click burn button.

Now sit back and wait.

After the burning process the cd tray will automatically opens.